# Output PHP already encode to json, and send to javascript to be json, not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm do output with json_encode to sending to javascript, with this code.

```
<?php

    include "Connection.php";

    $syntax_query = "select * from product";

    $thisExecuter = mysqli_query($conn, $syntax_query);

    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thisExecuter)){
        
        array_push(
            $result,
            array(
                "id"       => $row["product_id"],
                "name"        => $row["product_name"]
            )
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

    ?>
```

so output show like this,

[{"id":"121353568","name":"Baju Casual - Black"},{"id":"556903232","name":"Tas LV - Red"},{"id":"795953280","name":"Sword - Wood"},{"id":"834032960","name":"Scooter - Iron Plate"}]

and code javascript like this

```
function showHint() {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        var obj = this.responseText;
        
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = obj.id;
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "Download.php");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

so obj.id its not working, output show undifined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ajax calls when I want to call a Php file and get a response from the same as below to try once that as I have shown. Before moving with Ajax you must need jquery to be imported into the calling file.

---

If Jquery is imported then ignore the steps

---

Here are steps,

1. Go to the link https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js copy whole content (use ctl+A to select whole content and ctl+C to copy)
2. Open a new file in the current project folder and paste the copied content (use ctl+V to paste) save it as 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js'
3. Import the js file in the HTML file in script tag as shown '

Now, this is the ajax example to call the PHP file and to get a response

```js
function showHint() {
//since you have used GET method I have used here GET but You can use POST also here 
 $.ajax({
    url: 'Download.php',
    type: 'get',
//if any value you want to pass then uncomment below line
//    data: {'name_to_pass':'value'}, 
//the variable can be accessed in the php file by 'name to pass' under $_GET['name_to_pass'] or $_POST['name_to_pass'] based on type
    success: function(res)
    {
      //  open DevTool console to see results
      console.log(JSON.parse(res));
    }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a JSON.parse in the response, something like `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`.

And also I can see the result is an Array so you will need to iterate `obj`

```
obj.forEach(item => { 
  document.getElement("txtHint").innerHTML = item.id;
});
```

Comment: still not working T.T, but thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you should define the response type as json

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showHint() {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        **var obj = this.responseText;**
        
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = obj.id;
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "Download.php");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When you get the responseText it's text, not an object.
`var obj = this.responseText;` should be `let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`
Then you can access obj.id as a property.